# File Size before Upload not before move in PHP

Tags: php

IS it any way to validate on file size in php before upload. I have added java-script validation but user disabled  client side validation and upload files in GB's so browser of user wait more then 30 minutes to upload then at the time of move file in php i display message file size is greater. User irritates. Please let me know any way to validate file size at the time of file upload

Comment: It's not possible, because client upload something on server and then is call php to process it, so you can do this only with server settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible do this in php, because when you upload data, webserver handle request and then execute php script, so, user must upload his request first.

If user has disabled javascript you can limit max request body, so webserver cannot accpet bigger requests

For apache webserver you can set [limitrequestbody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)